# Oracle and java autostart

Tags: java, oracle, autostart

Like in the title. I recently noticed that after I've installed Oracle 11g on Windows it has been autostarting everytime i turn my pc on, the same thing is happening with java. Where I can turn this setting off?

Answer (score 2):

Click Windows Start Button -> type `msconfig` and press enter.
Open the `Startup` tab, and disable what you need to disable

Comment: The thing is I don't see Oracle and Java in Startup applications

Comment: You're mistaken. Nobody told you to look at "Start" (left lower corner on Windows OS), but operating system's **services**. An alternative to msconfig is to run Control Panel > Administrative tools > Services.